# I need some help to find some Kali Linux ARM Image (raspberry)

Tags: kali-linux, raspberry-pi

I was wondering if anyone of you have in your files any older version of the Kali Linux ARM Images for Raspberry Pi (2,3,4). **I need an image before the "2020.3"**. Can help me? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Older ARM images can still be dowloaded from the official site:

- https://images.kali.org/arm-images/kali-linux-2019.4-rpi.img.xz
- https://images.kali.org/arm-images/kali-linux-2020.1-rpi.img.xz
- https://images.kali.org/arm-images/kali-linux-2020.2-rpi.img.xz